# Is it possible to list embedded folder contents?

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

Is it possible to list embedded folder contents?

I want to load all files from specific folder(s), w/o having to edit file list after adding each new file.

**Edit:**

If I try `sys.FileSystem.ReadDirectory()`, I get a

> "You cannot access the sys package while targeting flash (for
>   sys.FileSystem)"

error for Flash. But when I look in HaxeFlixel `FlxAssets.hx` file - somehow it does the trick for flash target.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array containing the paths to all embedded images like so:

```
import openfl.Assets;

var imagePaths:Array<String> = Assets.list(AssetType.IMAGE);
```

If you don't specify an `AssetType`, `list()` returns all embedded assets regardless of their type.

Answer (score 0):

On neko and cpp targets, You've got the sys.Filesystem.readDirectory(path:Stringh) method, that will give you all files and directories in the specific folder path. Is that what you're after?

Comment: I get You cannot access the sys package while targeting flash (for sys.FileSystem) error for Flash. But when I look in Flixel FlxAssets file - somehow it does the trick for flash target.

Comment: I guess that Flixel handle assets something like OpenFL does, wich means that on Flash target, known files can be loaded. You have no "dynamic" access to the filesystem though, to check wether the file actually exist or to list the files in a specific directory. This must be asked for from a server solution with filesystem access (php, java, neko, node.js...)